# insert data to mssql with webservice from Android

Tags: android, asp.net, sql-server, json, web-services

my webservice codes here:

```
 namespace AndWeb
{
public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e1)
    {


        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        List<Employee> eList = new List<Employee>();

        string temp = "";
        try
        {

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
 WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            connection.Open();

            string query = "select * from AndLogin";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sorgu, connection);


            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Employee e = new Employee();
                e.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"].ToString());
                e.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                e.SurName = reader["SurName"].ToString();
                e.Password = reader["Password"].ToString();

                eList.Add(e);


             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            temp = "Hata : " + ex.Message;
        }
        string ans = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eList, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

        temp = "{\"login\":" + ans + "}";
       Response.Write(temp);

    }
}
public class Employee
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public string SurName;
    public string Password;


}
```

}

webservice Json output is:

{"login":[ { "ID": 1112602055, "Name": "david", "SurName": "suarez", "Password": "****" }, { "ID": 1112602056, "Name": "damon", "SurName": "gomez", "Password": "****" }, { "ID": 1112602057, "Name": "kinsella", "SurName": "mark", "Password": "****" } ]}

i can read my datas from mssql with JSON but how can i insert data to sql from my android application??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many tutorials out there explaining how to execute a SQL statement from .Net
You should try reading some of them.

By the way, What you're showing is not a traditional .Net Webservice, it's a WebForm.

Your approach can still work, but your application would need to post data to the web form, same as the user clicking the submit button in a browser.

I don't want to go into too much detail, because I feel you should try and find the answer yourself, but

To insert the data, instead of calling

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You need to add parameters to your cmd object. Yyou should be able to read them from the Request.Form object if your post was successful.. i.e.

cmd.Parameters.Add("SomeName", Request.Form["SomeName"]);

you would then use

```
cmd.ExecuteNonReader();
```

Comment: can u share a tutorial about this? :)

Comment: [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSBx9_eddmo)
 and 
[dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient)

Comment: Thans a lot.. But any tutorial about this and Android??

Comment: [Try this](http://23.92.30.78/?q=android+tutorial%2C+sql+tutorial%2C+c%23+tutorial)